# Pdftohtml doesn't work on the online server

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec, pdf-to-html

I am using [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net) to convert pdf files dynamically to html files, I do this through PHP on a linux server.

I use the following code to test the pdf to html conversion:

```
$output = shell_exec("cd pdftohtml_linux; pdftohtml test.pdf");
```

It doesn't work, and `echo $output` doesn't output anything, although any other linux command such as `ls` and `make` work perfectly fine and display the corresponding output.

The strange thing is that the exact same code works like a charm on localhost on ubuntu 12.04, the html files are generated and there's some output from `shell_exec()` logging the number of pages and some other stuff. According to `phpinfo()` the web server's system is: Linux infong 2.4 #1 SMP

Any idea on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

On your server, if you have PHP < 5.4.0, you might have [`safe_mode` on](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php). This will be output by `phpinfo()` (look for `safe_mode` on the page).

If it's the case and you have access to the server's configuration, change `safe_mode` to `"0"` in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`.

Comment: No.. ```safe_mode``` is set to off

Answer (score 0):

For whatever this answer is worth...

you need to find where your pdftohtml is installed first. Its usually in `/usr/bin/`

Then run `shell_exec("/usr/bin/pdftohtml test.pdf");`

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the same problem. I fixed it by adding ' 2>&1'

```
exec("pdftohtml test.pdf 2>&1");
```

See if this works for you